# How to implement a modifiable table on a web page?

Tags: web-applications, webforms, wiki

I would like to create an HTML page that contains a table, where one column is editable by any user (after logging in). (As a bonus, the table should be sortable on any column.)

It's sort of like a wiki page, except the users are not supposed to edit wiki source code, but simply modify values in the modifiable column of the table.

Are there any packages for that? Maybe a wiki plugin?

Comment: Of course, user changes should not just be local, but actually stored on the server.

Comment: No, it's not for ASP.NET. It will most likely run on a linux server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. One way is to use ExtJs.

Here is an ExtJs [editable grid sample](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/edit-grid.html).

There is also a [jQuery grid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html).

Answer (score 1):

Quick method: use Google Docs. Might not be applicable, though.

If that's not possible,

Use any JS library's table component for sorting.

Use any server-side scripting technology to populate the cell from a persistent store. A database is probably overkill for this, but if you do not use a database- for instance, if you use a regular file to store the row- be careful with concurrent writes to your persistent store.

Also, make the row an input field, enclose the table in a form and make the form's action some kind of server-side technology that writes the value in the input field to the persistent store. CGI would be perfectly appropriate for this, but you'll want to use whatever's available on your web server.

Comment: Thanks! I do think that an actual database (mySQL, etc.) would be overkill, so I'd prefer a flat file instead. Any tips on the issue of concurrent writes?

Comment: If your platform supports file locking, that's a good option.